# How to fix Multiprocessing Pool, used 100% of CPU

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, cpu-usage

I've been for several days I can't figure out how to find a solution for my script.

My script does nothing but search for certain files on X websites.

The lists of sites on which the script searches can be from 2000 to 50,000 websites, but even if I try with a list of 200 sites the same problem remains, CPU AT 100%.

Can anyone tell me what I'm wrong and maybe figure out how to fix it?

Thank you

Ps. I have inserted all the modules that the script requires and only the part that should be of interest for multiprocessing.

```
    try:
    import os
    import easygui
    import pyautogui as py
    import datetime
    import pwinput
    import json
    from queue import Queue
    from queue import Empty
    from collections import Counter
    import random
    import string
    import threading
    import subprocess
    import multiprocessing
    from multiprocessing import Process, Pool, Value, Lock
    import grequests
    import requests
    from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
    from requests.exceptions import HTTPError
    import time
    from os import path
    from zipfile import *
    from pathlib import Path
    from time import sleep
    import socket
    from datetime import datetime
    import re
    from re import findall as reg
    import urllib.request as urlrq
    from urllib.parse import urlparse
    import certifi
    import ssl
    import urllib3
    from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
    from urllib3 import disable_warnings

    disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
    import validators
    from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
    import colorama
    from colorama import Fore, Back, Style, init
    import itertools
    import ctypes
except ImportError:
    import os

    os.system('pip install grequests')
    os.system('pip install pwinput')
    os.system('pip install colorama')
    os.system('pip install apscheduler')
    os.system('pip install requests')
    os.system('pip install findall')
    os.system('pip install http.client')
    os.system('pip install psutil')
    os.system('pip install validators')
    os.system('pip install itertools')
    os.system('pip install urllib3')
    os.system('pip install easygui')
    os.system('pip install pyautogui')
    os.system('pip install zipfile')


colorama.init(autoreset=True)



R = Fore.RED
P = Fore.MAGENTA
A = Fore.CYAN
G = Fore.GREEN
B = Fore.BLUE
W = Fore.WHITE
Y = Fore.YELLOW
C = Fore.RESET
CC = Style.RESET_ALL
PP = Style.BRIGHT + Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX
AA = Style.BRIGHT + Fore.LIGHTCYAN_EX
RR = Style.BRIGHT + Fore.LIGHTRED_EX
YY = Style.BRIGHT + Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX



lock = threading.Lock()
NUM_PROCESSES = int()



class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self, initval=0):
        self.val = Value('i', initval)
        self.lock = Lock()


    def increment(self):
        with self.lock:
            self.val.value += 1

    def value(self):
        with self.lock:
            return self.val.value

def updateTitle(NUM_PROCESSES,counterhits,counterdone,countersl,counterml,counter_listok,username):
    while True:
        hits = int(counterhits.value())
        done = int(counterdone.value())
        shtot = int(countersl.value())
        maitot = int(counterml.value())
        listok = num_listok + int(counter_listok)
        remain_scan = listok - hits
        elapsed = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(time.time() - start))
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW(f'Site Valid For: {listok} | Started: {hits} | Complete: {done} | Remain: {remain_scan} | Sl Found: {shtot} | Ml Found: {maitot} | Threads: {NUM_PROCESSES} | Time elapsed: {elapsed}')
        sleep(0.3)



def worker_main(queue,counterhits,counterdone,countersl,counterml):
    while True:
        try:
            site = queue.get(block=False)
        except queue.Empty:
            sleep(0.5)
            continue
        except queue.Full:
            sleep(0.5)
            continue
        if site is None:
            break
        start_time_base = time.process_time()
        counterhits.increment()
        do_work(site,countersl,counterml,counterdone)
        counterdone.increment()
        end_time_base = time.process_time()


start = time.time()
def main():
    global username
    listok = int(len(filter_data))
    the_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    counterhits = Counter(0)
    counterdone = Counter(0)
    countersl = Counter(0)
    counterml = Counter(0)
    counter_listok = int(listok)
    the_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(NUM_PROCESSES, worker_main,(the_queue,counterhits,counterdone,countersl,counterml))
    procs = [Process(target=updateTitle, args=(NUM_PROCESSES,counterhits,counterdone,countersl,counterml,counter_listok,username), daemon=True) for i in range(1)]
    prefix = ['http://']

    for i in range(NUM_PROCESSES):
        for site_il in filter_data:
            site_or = site_il.rstrip("\n")
            if (site_or.startswith("http://")) :
                site_or = site_or.replace("http://","")
            elif (site_or.startswith("https://")) :
                site_or = site_or.replace("https://","")
            site_or = site_or.rstrip()
            site_or = site_or.split('/')[0]
            if ('www.' in site_or) :
                site_or = site_or.replace("www.", "")

            sitexx = [sub + site_or for sub in prefix]
            for site in sitexx:
                the_queue.put(site)
        the_queue.put(None)

    for p in procs: p.start()


    the_queue.close()
    the_queue.join_thread()
    the_pool.close()
    the_pool.join()
    end_time_base = time.perf_counter()


    for p in procs: p.join()

    os.system('pause>nul')
```

Comment: Looks like you're adding multiple copies of the same tasks to your queue, multiplied by the number of processes. What's the real value of `NUM_PROCESSES` anyway, is it really zero? (And why use such an odd way to write zero?)

Comment: But in any case, isn't the point of using multiprocessing to use more CPU than threads would? How are you certain you're seeing an actual problem?